# User profile detail in vf page

Tags: visualforce, profile, user, user-management

I just wanted to show the "My Profile" details (associated with a user) into a vf page with its header. The page, I want to refer has following url:-

https://cs52.salesforce.com/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed

I have a Community page with a apex link "My Profile" which redirects to the above page snapshot on click. but my requirement is that i want to show the above page into my community vf page.(Only the green section) So that user can edit its information. I tried to add a iframe into my vf page with the above specified link. But it did not work.

You can try with following uri after your base url. See below snapshot.

_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: If you could explain your requirement a bit more its easy to help you .Welcome to the site .To get clear response ,please post your query with details and also indicate what have you tried and where you are blocked

Comment: Mohith, Actually I have a Community page with a apex link "My Profile" which redirects to the above page snapshot on click. but my requirement is that i want to show the above page into my community vf page.(Only the green section) So that user can edit its information. 
I tried to add a iframe into my vf page with the above specified link. But it did not work.

Comment: can you add same description in your question to avoid people closing this

Comment: try this `<apex:page >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>`

Comment: Hi Tushar, This gives me chatter feed, I need the whole user profile page. Overview tab etc.

Comment: @nitinpanchal can you add code for your page & class.

Comment: unclear? He wants to display his profile info in a visualforce page and be able to edit this info. It's not unclear, it's just not readily possible. For example; I've often wanted to let an admin set a users working hours from a central place where they admin could administer that and other user profile edits from one visual force page. such is useful with call queues. If you don't understand don't down vote, just stay out.